# Switch from IClientMessageInspector to IParameterInspector?

Tags: wcf, logging, configuration, communication, inspector

My winform WCF client have a custom IEndpointBehavior where the ApplyClientBehavior method looks like this :

```
public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
            clientRuntime.CallbackDispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());      
        }
```

To get hold of the serlized parameters I have changed from IClientMessageInspector and IDispatchMessageInspector to IParameterInspector. How to I convert the IEndpointBehavior to load this IParameterInspector instead?

I have found this :

```
SimpleServiceClient proxy = new SimpleServiceClient();
proxy.Endpoint.Contract.Operations[0].Behaviors.Add(new MyParameterInspector());
```

My client is however created from CreateChannel so Behaviors do not exists, instead there is a OperationsBehaviors that will not take a IParameterInspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure its behavior in the configuration file,Here is a demo:

```
          public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        foreach (ClientOperation op in clientRuntime.Operations)
            op.ParameterInspectors.Add(new Inspector());
    }
```

This is ApplyClientBehavior.

```
    public class Inspector : IParameterInspector
{
    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
                "IParameterInspector.AfterCall called for {0} with return value {1}.",
                     operationName,
                    returnValue.ToString()
                    );
    }

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IParameterInspector.BeforeCall called for {0}.", operationName);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Inspector implements the interface of IParameterInspector.

```
            <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Test">
                <clientInterceptors/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add
              name="clientInterceptors"
              type="Client.InspectorInserter,Client, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
```

This is the configuration file.

[image]

This is the result of the client-side running.

Here is the reference link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-or-modify-parameters

Answer (score 0):

It is done by adding the IParameterInspector to each operation liket his :

```
public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {     
            foreach (var clientOperation in clientRuntime.Operations)
                clientOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());

            foreach (var clientOperation in clientRuntime.CallbackDispatchRuntime.Operations)
                clientOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
        }
```